# How to reorder a DataFrame based on the column of the other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have two Dataframes, with one shared column with identical values, but in a different order

```
df1

    shared_column    column1
0   Z59FTQD X 0 X 243   0
1   0JP29SK X 0 X 243   0
2   0JP29SK X 1 X 243   0
3   0JP29SK X 2 X 243   0
4   0JP29SK X 3 X 243   0

df2
    shared_column    column2
0   ICE2DJP X 0 X 4     ICE2DJP
1   ICE2DJP X 0 X 13    ICE2DJP
2   ICE2DJP X 0 X 20    ICE2DJP
3   ICE2DJP X 0 X 23    ICE2DJP
4   ICE2DJP X 0 X 28    ICE2DJP
```

The 'shared_column' in both datasets have the same number of rows and values, but are in a different order.

How can I reorder my 'df1' Dataframe columns, based on the order of the 'shared_column' in 'df2'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column to df1, called sort_col in the example here. Then you can just use .sort_values(). You can set ascending to True if needed. You may also want to use reset_index() after you sort.

```
df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"[ ]{2,}", header=None, names=['idx', 'shared_column', 'column1'])

df2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"[ ]{2,}", header=None, names=['idx', 'shared_column', 'column2'])

df1['sort_col'] = df2['shared_column']

df1.sort_values(by='sort_col', inplace=True, ascending=False)

print(df1)

    idx shared_column   column1 sort_col
0   0   Z59FTQD X 0 X 243   0   ICE2DJP X 0 X 4
4   4   0JP29SK X 3 X 243   0   ICE2DJP X 0 X 28
3   3   0JP29SK X 2 X 243   0   ICE2DJP X 0 X 23
2   2   0JP29SK X 1 X 243   0   ICE2DJP X 0 X 20
1   1   0JP29SK X 0 X 243   0   ICE2DJP X 0 X 13
```